# OOM issue after validation dataset iterator is reset three times

Tags: validation, tensorflow, iterator, dataset

I recently changed a set of my tensorflow code from queue to dataset to take advantage of the iterator reset function for validation dataset. It works fine except always OOM issue in the middle of the third iteration of validation. 
(the validation has 700+ steps, the code is always crashing at around 400+ step in the third validation)

```
*val_step = 434, step_cost = 62.8875665665,  total_cost = 24353.1902707
2017-10-27 11:47:08.602743: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:273] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of   memory trying to allocate 7.50MiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
2017-10-27 11:47:08.605489: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 0,      Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in    use in bin.
2017-10-27 11:47:08.605520: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 0,      Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in    use in bin.
2017-10-27 11:47:08.605536: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 0,      Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in    use in bin.
....
....
....
2017-10-27 11:47:08.749632: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 14.    83GiB
2017-10-27 11:47:08.749646: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats:
Limit:                 15927646618
InUse:                 15927646464
MaxInUse:              15927646464
NumAllocs:               457706168
MaxAllocSize:             42035200

2017-10-27 11:47:08.750506: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:                                        277] ****************************************************************************************************
2017-10-27 11:47:08.750540: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1192] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating    tensor with shape[128,60,256]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 1091, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 1087, in main
    training()
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 746, in training
    batch_check = FLAGS.val_batch_check)
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 411, in process_chunk
    feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[128,60,256]
   [[Node: model_att_1/attention/strided_slice_199 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=5,           ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=5, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:       0"](model_att_1/attention/concat, model_att_1/attention/strided_slice_199/stack, model_att_1/attention/               strided_slice_199/stack_1, model_att_1/attention/strided_slice_199/stack_2)]]
   [[Node: div_1/_69195 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",         send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_11676_div_1",       tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'model_att_1/attention/strided_slice_199', defined at:
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 1091, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 1087, in main
    training()
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 594, in training
    scope=model_scope)
  File "lstm_cls_att_emb.py", line 320, in build_model
    name="attention")
  File "/data/wzhan/workspace/new_fraud_models/attention_emb.py", line 223, in __init__
    memory = self.memory[:, time_step:time_step+attention_window_size, :]  # batch_size * window_size * dim
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 509, in _SliceHelper
    name=name)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 677, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3744, in            strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in      apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[128,60,256]
   [[Node: model_att_1/attention/strided_slice_199 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=5,           ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=5, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:       0"](model_att_1/attention/concat, model_att_1/attention/strided_slice_199/stack, model_att_1/attention/               strided_slice_199/stack_1, model_att_1/attention/strided_slice_199/stack_2)]]
   [[Node: div_1/_69195 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",         send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_11676_div_1",       tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]*
```

each time, after current model saved, I call

```
sess.run(validation_iterator.initializer)
```

to reset the iterator and start the validation steps.

Other information:
Tensorflow 1.3.0
tensorlayer 1.6.5
cuda 8
cudnn 6